# Can I copy the table structure of a #temp table to a new physical table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, temporary-tables

I have a `#tempTable` that was created using

```
SELECT *
INTO #tempTable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=MyFileName.xls', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Is there an easy way to copy the table structure of the `#tempTable` to a new physical table?

The temp table contains a lot of columns which contain numbers, dates, decimals, and strings, and I do not want to have to identify and manually define every column.

I am using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use the same approach you used to create the #temp table?

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.NewTable FROM #tempTable;
```

Comment: ... *grumbles*  Beat me to it!

Comment: Because NewTable doesn't exist... Will that work if the table doesn't exist?

Comment: You created #tempTable and it didn't exist. This is exactly what [`SELECT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) does.

Comment: Yes, it will work.  It will create the new (physical) table with the same structure

Comment: Thank you, for some reason it never occurred to me that the same syntax would work for permanent tables too, and Google wasn't being very helpful. I feel like an idiot now... :)

Comment: Just to add a small more into to what @AaronBertrand already said that when you do a select * into Newtable from #temptable, it will copy the data as well. If you just want the table structure (not the data) then select * into Newtable from #temptable where 1=2 ... notice the where clause which is always false and hence will create a table but with no data.

Comment: @Kin I've used SELECT TOP 0 * INTO Newtable FROM #temptable, since sometimes [1 = 2 is true](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/first1eq2.html), and you should not take that risk.

Comment: @daveboltman ..can you give an example where 1=2 is true ?

Comment: @DaveBoltman Personal preference. While you can make some silly math thing from a textbook work on paper, this is not a concern in SQL Server. Also I think it is often `WHERE 1 = 0`.

Comment: @Kin sorry, it was just a joke - AaronBertrand is exactly right - it's just my personal preference - both methods work (`TOP 0` or `WHERE 1=2`). Of course 1 is **never** equal to 2, or 0, or any other number. It is just a mathematical trick, which appears to be true, but is not. Please see  https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/first1eq2.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just do :

```
select *
into dbo.NewTable
FROM #tempTable
```